# Separating requests to same page in load testing

Tags: asp.net, .net, performance-testing

I've recorded a web performance test in Visual Studio 2013 and then created a load test off of that.

In the load test results, I want to differentiate between two requests to the same page (different form parameters passed in). How would I do that?

I'll try to illustrate the problem in screenshots:

Here's my web performance test:
[image]

And here are the load test results:
[image]

I want the Respond page to be shown as two separate entries in this results table. Any ideas?

Comment: "Reparating" is not a word. Which word did you mean?

Comment: @JohnSaunders, my bad. I meant separating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the "reporting name" properties of the two requests to different values. These can be set via the property panel, also via the "set request details" command icon just above the panel containing the web test.